# How to split column which have null value and some value both in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file in which i have different types of values. 
I need to split them into three columns.
Can you please help me how to do this?

I want to split 'COMPONENT_IDS' col. into three Col. - DOC_ID, DOC_TITLE, PROD

example:

```
COMPONENT_IDS
0
ENC-010864-13;INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014
0
INK-MET-100 vs 300;INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose;Invokana
```

OutPut:

```
DOC_ID               DOC_TITLE                                    PROD
NULL                 NULL                                         NULL
ENC-010864-13        INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014         NULL
NULL                 NULL                                         NULL
INK-MET-100 vs 300   INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose  Invokana
```

Comment: How working solution below?

Answer (score 0):

First replace `0` to missing values and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for new `DataFrame` and assign back to new columns:

```
c = ['DOC_ID','DOC_TITLE','PROD']
df[c] = df.pop('COMPONENT_IDS').replace('0',np.nan).str.split(';', expand=True)
print (df)
               DOC_ID                                    DOC_TITLE      PROD
0                 NaN                                          NaN       NaN
1       ENC-010864-13         INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014      None
2                 NaN                                          NaN       NaN
3  INK-MET-100 vs 300  INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose  Invokana
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.pop('COMPONENT_IDS').replace('0',np.nan).str.split(';', expand=True))
                    0                                            1         2
0                 NaN                                          NaN       NaN
1       ENC-010864-13         INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014      None
2                 NaN                                          NaN       NaN
3  INK-MET-100 vs 300  INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose  Invokana
```

Comment: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key. This error is coming

Comment: @alka change `.str.split(';', expand=True)` to `.str.split(';', n=2, expand=True)`, because there is more `;` like `2`